# Ubuntu 20.04 will not restart properly

Tags: 20.04, restart

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and I am having an issue with rebooting. when I tell it to reboot, it will start to restart as normal, it will show a screen with a blinking cursor, and it will act like i cut the power, with the hard drive coming to a halt instead of it spinning down. If I wait 15-20 seconds it will come back on on its own. on 18.04 it never did this.

Comment: Shutdown works as normal